# Function won't stop running

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I seem to have a very bad problem with my code. The fist time I called the battle function it works fine, but the second time I call it, it just uses the parameter that was passed during the first call. I think the function is still running from the first call. Here is my code I tried to only put the essential parts in:

```
var player = {
    // Name
    // Position
    totalHealth: 20, // total Health
    currentHealth : 20, // current Health
    Level: 1, // Level
    // Defense
    // Attack
    // Luck
    Win: false,
    EXP: 0,
    EXPNeededCalculation: function (Level) {
        return (Level * 100) - player.EXP;
    },
    EXPGainedCalculation: function (opponentLevel, playerCurrentHealth, playerTotalHealth) {
        return player.EXP += Math.ceil(opponentLevel * 10 - ((playerTotalHealth - playerCurrentHealth) / 2));
    },
    // Items are in an object {Description:  powers, used : false, use() : yadayadayada}
    DefenseDoubled: false,
    attack: function (Attack, Luck, opponentDefense) {
        var possibleAttacks = [];
        var possibleDefense = [999]; // arbitrary number to fill one space
        for (var i = 0 ; i < Luck ; i++) {
            possibleAttacks.push(Math.ceil(Math.random() * Attack));
        };
        possibleAttacks.sort(); 
        var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
        if (a > 7) {
            for (var x = 0 ; x < opponentDefense ; x++) {
                possibleDefense.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * opponentDefense) - 1);
            };
        }
        possibleDefense.sort(); 
        if (possibleDefense[0] <= 0) {
            var b = 0;
        } else {
            var b = 998; // arbitrary number
        }

        if (b === 0) {
            player["attackDamage"] = 0;
        } else {
            player["attackDamage"] = possibleAttacks[possibleAttacks.length - 1];
        }


    },
    defend: function() {
        player.Defense *= 2;
        player.DefenseDoubled = true;
    },
    undefend: function() {
        player.Defense /= 2;
        player.DefenseDoubled = false;
    }
};

function opponent(Level, Type, Name) {
    this.Name = Name;
    this.Level = Level;
    this.Type = Type;
    this.Health = calcHealth(Level);
    this.currentHealth = calcHealth(Level);
    this.Defense = calcStats(Level, Type);
    this.Attack = calcStats(Level, Type);
    this.Luck = calcStats(Level, Type);
    this.attackDamage =  0;
    this.DefenseDoubled = false;
    this.Poisoned = false;
    this.Burned = false;
    this.Frozen = false;

    function calcHealth(Level) {
        this.Health = Level * 5;
        this.currentHealth = this.Health;
        return this.Health; return this.currentHealth;
    };

    function calcStats(Level, Type) {
        this.Defense = Level * 2;
        this.Attack = Math.ceil(Level * 1.5);
        this.Luck = Math.ceil(Level * 1.25);
        return this.Defense ; return this.Attack ; return this.Luck; 
        if (Type === "snake" || Type === "Snake") {
            this.Luck += 1;
        }
    };
    this.attack = function(Attack, Luck, playerDefense) {
        var possibleAttacks = [];
        var possibleDefense = [999]; // arbitrary number to fill one space
        for (var i = 0 ; i < Luck ; i++) {
            possibleAttacks.push(Math.ceil(Math.random() * Attack));
        };
        possibleAttacks.sort(); 
        var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
        if (a > 7) {
            for (var x = 0 ; x < playerDefense ; x++) {
                possibleDefense.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * playerDefense) - 1);
            };
        } 
        possibleDefense.sort(); 
        if (possibleDefense[0] <= 0) {
            var b = 0;
        } else {
            var b = 998; // arbitrary number
        }
        if (b === 0) {
            this.attackDamage = 0;
        } else {
            this.attackDamage = possibleAttacks[possibleAttacks.length - 1];
        }
    };

    this.defend = function() {
        this.Defense *= 2;
        this.DefenseDoubled = true;
    };
    this.undefend = function() {
        this.Defense /= 2;
        this.DefenseDoubled = false;
    }
}
$yesButton.click(function() {
yPressed = true;
if (value === 4 && yPressed === true) {
        addToValue(1);
        yPressed = false;
        $showBattleSummaryBox();
        $statsBox.append("<p class='center'>Health: " + player.totalHealth + "</p>");
        $battleSummaryBox.append("<p id='playersHealth' class='center'>Your Health: " + player.currentHealth + "/" + player.totalHealth + "</p>");
        $outputBox.append("<p>On the right is your Battle Summary Box. Your health has also shown up. If your health reaches zero, then you will faint, but if your enemy's health reaches zero, then you win.</p>");
        $outputBox.append("<p>Battles are turn-based. You will make an action and then your opponent will. During your turn, you can either attack, defend, or use an item.</p>");
        $outputBox.append("<p>I happen to have a level 1 python for you to practice with. </p>");
        scroll($outputBox);
        var e1 = new opponent(1, "snake", "Python"); 
        $battleSummaryBox.append("<p id='opponentsHealth' class='center'>Enemy's Health: " + e1.currentHealth + "/" + e1.Health + "</p>");
        $showBattleCommandBox();
        battle(e1);
    } 
});

function battle(opponent) {
    $battleOutputBox.append("<p>You make the first move!</p>");
    $("#opponentsHealth").text("Enemy's Health: " + opponent.currentHealth + "/" + opponent.Health);
    battleInProgress = true;
    $attackButton.click(function () {
        if (player.Win === false && battleInProgress === true) {
            player.attack(player.Attack, player.Luck, opponent.Defense);

            // additional Item effects
            if (player.Items.hasOwnProperty("Poison Arrows")) {
                var e = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10); 
                if (e > 7) {
                    opponent.Poisoned = true;
                }
            } else if (player.Items.hasOwnProperty("Fire Blade")) {
                var e = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10); 
                if (e > 7) {
                    opponent.Burned = true;
                    player.attackDamage += 3;
                }
            } else if (player.Items.hasOwnProperty("Blade of Luck")) {
                var e = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10); 
                if (e > 7) {
                    player.attackDamage += 1;
                } 
            }

            opponent.currentHealth -= player.attackDamage;
            $("#opponentsHealth").text("Enemy's Health: " + opponent.currentHealth + "/" + opponent.Health);
            if (player.attackDamage === 0) {
                $battleOutputBox.append("<p>Your attack has been blocked</p>");
            } else {
                $battleOutputBox.append("<p>You inflicted " + player.attackDamage + " damage.</p>");
                scroll($battleOutputBox);
            }
            if (opponent.DefenseDoubled === true) {
                opponent.undefend();
            }
            if (opponent.Poisoned === true) {
                Poison();
            } else if (opponent.Burned === true) {
                Burn();
            } else if (opponent.Frozen === true) {
                Freeze();
            } 
            if (opponent.currentHealth <= 0) {
                player.Win = true;
                return postBattle(opponent);
            } else {opponentTurn();}
        }
    });

    $defendButton.click(function () {
        if (player.Win === false && battleInProgress === true) {
            player.defend();
            $battleOutputBox.append("<p>Your defense has been doubled for one turn.</p>");
            if (opponent.DefenseDoubled === true) {
                opponent.undefend();
            }
            if (opponent.Poisoned === true) {
                Poison();
            } else if (opponent.Burned === true) {
                Burn();
            } else if (opponent.Frozen === true) {
                Freeze();
            } 
            if (opponent.currentHealth <= 0) {
                player.Win = true;
                return postBattle(opponent);
            } else {opponentTurn();}
        }
    }); 

    $useItemButton.click(function () {
        if (player.Win === false && battleInProgress === true) {
            if ($useItemSelection.html().length > 15) {
                var itemBeingUsed = $("select[name='useItemSelection'] option:selected").text();
                if (itemBeingUsed === "Book of Spells" && player.Items.bookOfSpells.used === false) {
                    player.Items.bookOfSpells.use();
                    console.log(player.Items.bookOfSpells.effect);
                    if (player.Items.bookOfSpells.effect === "burn" || player.Items.bookOfSpells.effect === "poison") {
                        $battleOutputBox.append("<p>You have " + player.Items.bookOfSpells.effect + "ed " + opponent.Name + ".</p>");
                        if (player.Items.bookOfSpells.effect === "burn") {
                            opponent.Burned = true;
                        } else {
                            opponent.Poisoned = true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $battleOutputBox.append("<p>You have froze " + opponent.Name + ".</p>");
                        opponent.Frozen = true;
                    }
                    player.Items.bookOfSpells.used = true;
                } else if (itemBeingUsed === "Shield Charm" && player.Items.shieldCharm.used === false) {
                    player.Items.shieldCharm.use();
                    $battleOutputBox.append("<p>You will block the next attack with your shield charm.</p>");
                    player.Items.shieldCharm.used = true;
                }
                if (opponent.Poisoned === true) {
                    Poison();
                } else if (opponent.Burned === true) {
                    Burn();
                } else if (opponent.Frozen === true) {
                    Freeze();
                } 
                if (opponent.currentHealth <= 0) {
                    player.Win = true;
                    return postBattle(opponent);
                } else {opponentTurn();}
            } else {
                var noUsableItemP = $("<p id='noUsableItemP'>You have no usable items. Select another command.</p>");
                $battleCommandPromptDiv.empty();
                $battleCommandPromptDiv.append(noUsableItemP);
            }
        }
    });

    function opponentTurn() {

        var c = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
        if (c > 5) {
            opponent.attack(opponent.Attack, opponent.Luck, player.Defense);
            if (player.Items.hasOwnProperty('shieldCharm')) {
                if (player.Items.shieldCharm.active) {
                    var d = 0;
                    player.Items.shieldCharm.active = false;
                } else {
                    var d = opponent.attackDamage;
                }
            } else {
                var d = opponent.attackDamage;
            }
            player.currentHealth -= d;
            $("#playersHealth").text("Your Health: " + player.currentHealth + "/" + player.totalHealth);
            if (d === 0) {
                $battleOutputBox.append("<p class='right'>You have blocked the attack.</p>");
            } else {
                $battleOutputBox.append("<p class='right'>" + d + " damage has been inflicted upon you.</p>");
                scroll($battleOutputBox);
            }
        } else {
            opponent.defend();
            $battleOutputBox.append("<p class='right'>" + opponent.Name + " has doubled his defense for one turn.</p>");
        }
        if (player.DefenseDoubled === true) {
            player.undefend();
        }
        if (player.currentHealth <= 0) {
            postBattle(opponent);
        }
    }
    function Poison() {
        opponent.currentHealth -= 1;
        $("#opponentsHealth").text("Enemy's Health: " + opponent.currentHealth + "/" + opponent.Health);
        $battleOutputBox.append("<p> " + opponent.Name + " was hurt by poison.</p>");
        scroll($battleOutputBox);
        $("#opponentStatus").empty();
        $("#opponentStatus").append("<p style='color: green;' id='status'>Poisoned</p>");
    }
    function Burn() {
        opponent.currentHealth -= 1;
        $("#opponentsHealth").text("Enemy's Health: " + opponent.currentHealth + "/" + opponent.Health);
        $battleOutputBox.append("<p> " + opponent.Name + " was hurt by burn.</p>");
        scroll($battleOutputBox);
        $("#opponentStatus").empty();
        $("#opponentStatus").append("<p style='color: red;' id='status'>Burned</p>");
    }
    function Freeze() {
        opponent.currentHealth -= 1;
        $("#opponentsHealth").text("Enemy's Health: " + opponent.currentHealth + "/" + opponent.Health);
        $battleOutputBox.append("<p> " + opponent.Name + " was hurt by freeze.</p>");
        scroll($battleOutputBox);
        $("#opponentStatus").empty();
        $("#opponentStatus").append("<p style='color: blue;' id='status'>Frozen</p>");
    }
}

function postBattle(opponentBattled) {
    if (player.Win === true) {
        addToValue(1); 
        inMaze = distance > 5 ? true : false;
        $battleOutputBox.append("<p>You have won! You have gained " + player.EXPGainedCalculation(opponentBattled.Level, player.currentHealth, player.totalHealth) + " EXP. You need " + player.EXPNeededCalculation(player.Level) + " EXP to level up.</p>");
        $battleOutputBox.append("<p>Click Yes to continue.</p>");
        scroll($battleOutputBox);
        player.Win = false;
        battleInProgress = false;
    } else { 
        $battleOutputBox.append('<p>You have fainted. Refresh to start over.</p>');
        // Fix to restart quest
    }
}

var e2 = new opponent(1, "Snake", "Rattler");  
inMaze = false;
battle(e2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `battle` function, you are binding click handlers.  These handlers are never unbound.  If you call `battle` again, you are binding **additional** handlers, you are not replacing them.  As a result, you now have 2 sets of handlers, one with the old `opponent` and one with the new.  Both will fire.

Comment: How do you unbound the handler, or replace them?

Comment: You can use `off` or `unbind`.

Comment: You can look at the documentation http://api.jquery.com/unbind/  http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 1):

For single page applications it is very good practice to use:

`$(selector").off("click").on("click", function(){ /* handler */ });`

Otherwise you bind multiple events to the same element.

Comment: I would just caution to be careful as this will unbind **all** click handlers.  I would suggest using namespacing to ensure only removing the appropriate handlers.  The [off documentation](http://api.jquery.com/off/) has some information on namespaces.